# Enable page module return 404

Tags: magento2, module

I have module settings when I specify disabled then the module page should return a 404 code

In the code, I get the value of the module but do not return 404 if the module is disabled

```
    <?php

namespace Mage\Faq\Helper;


use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;

    const XML_PATH_FAQ = 'faq/group_id/field_id';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http
     */
    private $_response;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory
     */
    private $_urlFactory;


    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
                                StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
                                \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
                                \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
                                \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context,
                                \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
    
    ) {
            $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->_context = $context;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnable()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('faq/group_id/field_id', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you save data into system configuration value are store in **core_config_data**. So that time you need to check module status by using \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager.

```
protected $moduleManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    ...
}
................................................
................................................

if ($this->moduleManager->isOutputEnabled('Vendorname_Modulename')) {
    //the module output is enabled
} else {
    //the module output is disabled
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***